# Is it possible to edit single words in a richtextbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, formatting, richtextbox

I'm trying to create a text editor that formats text according to set rules, as it's typed. For example, specific (pre-defined) words need to be underlined or coloured red, etc, so each time space is pressed, the program checks to see if the word qualifies for formatting and formats as needed. Problem is that I can't figure out how to edit the text on a word-by-word basis.

I created an event that watches for space to be pressed:

```
private void MainTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Space)
        wordAnalyser.AnalyseWord();
}
```

(wordAnalyser is an instance of the WordAnalyser class)

In WordAnalyser I get the word (code nicked from another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222988/get-the-last-word-entered-in-richtextbox-c-sharp), thanks @King King):

```
string word = null;
string fullText = new TextRange(MainTextBox.Document.ContentStart, MainTextBox.Document.ContentEnd).Text;
int startIndexOfWord = fullText.TrimEnd().LastIndexOf(' ');
if (startIndexOfWord != -1)
{
    word = fullText.Substring(startIndexOfWord + 1).TrimEnd();
}
```

And now the only solution that occurs to me is to get the entire textblock, take off the last word, format it, stick it back on, and stuff the whole thing back into the textbox, but that's such a messy way to do it.

I'm wondering if there's a way to format the word straight into the richtextbox without touching the rest of the text. I'm new to WPF so not so familiar with its capabilities, but I've had a look around and no-one seems to have had this question.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format words in RichTextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18092639/format-words-in-richtextbox)

Comment: @Sach Thanks, don't know why I didn't come across that! It solves half my problem but it uses event TextChanged and not KeyDown - I want to be able to trigger it on space only

Comment: Potential problems with triggering it on <kbd>Space</kbd>: what about when the user backspaces? Or pastes?

Comment: @Keith Stein Good point, thanks. How would you solve that?

Comment: My first thought would be to handle the `TextChanged` event. Compare the new text to the old one to determine what exactly has changed.